# Angular 9->10 migration. TypeError: core_1.virtualFs.createSyncHost is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

After `ng upgrade` **serve** runs into an error:

```
TypeError: core_1.virtualFs.createSyncHost is not a function
```

any ideas of how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error after upgrading. Removing the node_modules and re-installing the dependencies fixed the problem:

```sh
# with yarn
rm -rf node_modules && yarn 

# with npm
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out the changes in your Application during the upgrade process through the below link:

https://update.angular.io/#9.0:10.0l3

Check winch of this feature are using already in your app that causes to this error during your migration process.